# how to pass only two properties to a $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ANGULARJS Question:

I got an array of objects and I need to pass it to my $scope variable. The property that's creating a problem for me in special is the `user` property 
since it holds elements like the name and email it affects the way the filter i set in the HTML is filtering the objects I want to display. The object is a list of notes and I want to be able to filter them by content in the note( title and body text)

I have tried to delete the property user from the object with the code below, but that does not work. `$scope.notes` still loads that attribute.

Ideally I should be able to pass to `$scope.notes` only the title and body attributes. Any ideas of how to do that efficiently?

```
 var notes = notesService.notesObjectInService;
    for (var i = 0;  i < notes.length; i++) {
        delete notes[i].user;
    };

    $scope.notes = notes;
```

This is the json object passed to notes in the first line.

```
[{"id":184,
"title":"Mari",
"body":"Mae",
"created_at":"2015-05-09T03:23:04.250Z",
"updated_at":"2015-05-09T03:23:04.250Z",
"user_id":1,
"user":{"id":1,
"email":"vini@vini.com",
"created_at":"2015-04-24T22:49:21.797Z",
"updated_at":"2015-05-09T03:04:27.739Z",
"username":"vinivini"}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding this function to your notesService?

```
function getSummaryNotes() {
  var returnValue = [];

  for (var i = 0;  i < notes.length; i++) {
    var note = notes[i];
    returnValue.push({title: note.title, body: note.body});
  }

  return returnValue;
}
```

Where notes is your array of notes which presumably the service has access to.

Then you can do:

```
$scope.notes = notesService.getSummaryNotes();
```

Comment: that worked great! I just got a heads up that I should solve that in my back end though. I should not be passing to the service properties as the user details. Since that could turn into a security issue. I intend to implement that.

Comment: Indeed, your frontend should only be given what it needs. If it doesn't need to use/display the other information in the note then don't give it.